# Convert a string to a whitespace separated list w/quoted elements

Tags: python

Is there a simple way in Python to convert a string to a list using whitespaces as separators, but ignoring the whitespace within quoted text?  IE: each word is treated as a separate search term, but any quoted text is treated as one term.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, by using the [`shlex.split()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('Some whitespace "separated string"')
['Some', 'whitespace', 'separated string']
```